# How to solve this visual glitch in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, tabs, less, visual-glitch

I'm working on a small LESS frontend library, that I'm going to use in my future projects. I'm also planning to release it with an open source license, when it's done and infers to be useful.

This library is going to include fancy Chrome-styled tabs. The current implementation using CS3 border radius is rather rough, and is based on a fiddle I found on the internet, which doesn't have supported non-webkit browsers at all. Since it is going to be used on a wide-variety of projects, I have to make it compatible with most major browsers. After doing some tweaks, it look almost the same on FF and Chrome, but on Firefox it has some visual glitch.

Relevant LESS source parts:

```
// Tabs
.fancy-tabs(@tab-color; @active-tab-color; @hover-tab-color; @click-tab-color)
{
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type : none;
    line-height : 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;

    >li
    {
        .fancy-tab(@tab-color; @active-tab-color; @hover-tab-color; @click-tab-color);
    }
}

.fancy-tab(@tab-color; @active-tab-color; @hover-tab-color; @click-tab-color)
{
    // Links
    a
    {
        // To make the other parts of the tab clickable
        padding: 0 1em;
        margin: 0 -1em;

        display: inline-block;
        // max-width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

    // Styling the tab
    float : left;
    margin : 5px -10px 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px 170px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px 90px;
    padding : 0 30px 0 25px;
    height: 170px;
    background: @tab-color;
    position : relative;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    max-width : 200px;
    .transition(all .2s);

    // Indent the first child
    &:first-child
    {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    // Fancy rounding
    &:before, &:after{
        content : '';
        background : @transparent;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border-width: 10px;
        top: 0px;
        border-style : solid;
        position : absolute;
        .transition(inherit);
    }

    &:before{
        border-color : @transparent @tab-color @transparent @transparent;
        .rotate(48deg);
        left: -23px;
    }

    &:after{
        border-color : @transparent @transparent @transparent @tab-color;
        .rotate(-48deg);
        right: -17px;
    }

    // Colorize active tab

    &:active{
      background: @click-tab-color;
    }


    &:hover:before{
      border-color : @transparent @hover-tab-color @transparent @transparent;
    }


    &:hover:after{
      border-color : @transparent @transparent @transparent @hover-tab-color;
    }

    &:active:before{
        border-color : @transparent @click-tab-color @transparent @transparent;
    }


    &:active:after{
        border-color : @transparent @transparent @transparent @click-tab-color;
    }

    &.ac
    {
        z-index: 2;
        background: @active-tab-color !important;

        &:before{
            border-color : @transparent @active-tab-color @transparent @transparent;
        }


        &:after{
            border-color : @transparent @transparent @transparent @active-tab-color;
        }
    }


    // Applying pointer effects
    .hover(highlight, @hover-tab-color);
    .click(highlight, @click-tab-color);
}
```

fiddle using compiled CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/kdani3/G9QE9/1/

I think this problem is likely to be related to Gecko's border-radius rendering engine, but I don't know any workaround for it.

**Screenshot:**

[image: :]

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem in FF/Win7.

Comment: Looks fine on FF 20 on OSX.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! FF20 on Ubuntu draws those gray lines between the tabs as you can  see on the screenshot. If those lines don't appear on OSX and Windows, than maybe this problem is os or harware related.

Comment: You could also start removing stuff to the minimum where these lines are appearing, so it's going to be much easier to debug and stuff..